# Custom model method in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

In mongoose, If we want to have a custom method on the document, we can do it as follows:

```js
userSchema.methods.newLoginAttempt = async function newLoginAttempt(status) {
  const doc = this
  doc.logins.push({status, createdAt: new Date()})
  const newDoc = await doc.save()
  return newDoc 
}
const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema) // "users" collection
```

Then you can use it as:

```js
const doc = new UserModel({ name: "x" })
doc.newLoginAttempt("success")
```

I want to apply the same concept, but not on documents, but on models instead, I want to have a function which I can chain on the model as follows:

```js
UserModel.myCustomMethodToCall()
```

How?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, in the docs [Click me](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics)

it's called **statics**, you can use it as follows:

```js
const yourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... })
yourSchema.statics.youCustomMethod = function(){  }
mongoose.model('ModelName', yourSchema)
```

Then you can use it as:

```js
Model.youCustomMethod()
```

just the same way you can call a built-in mongoose method on the model, ex:

```js
Model.findById()
```